# How can I assert a method is called without executing the code within the method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, partial-mocks

Imagine that we have below code

```
public class test
  {
   public void Condition(x,y)
   {
       if (x == y)
       {
           methodOne();
       }
       else
       {
           methodTwo();
       }
   }
    public void methodOne(){//do some database stuff}
    public void methodTwo(){//do some database stuff}
 }
```

I want to assert that if methodone is get called when x==y or not but do not want my test to execute the code inside my method one as it will do some database stuff ...

I am writing something like this

```
 MockRepository mockRepository=new MockRepository();
 var Mock = mockRepository.PartialMock<test>();
 mock.Replay();
 mock.condition(1,1);
 mock.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.methodOne);
 mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

but it tries to run run the stuff in the method one as well and I do not want my test do the database connection , I just need to make sure my condition is work and it called or not.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: no, I think I should ! ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing your concerns, business logic and data access, in one class. You need to think about [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Your `public void Condition(x,y)` should probably be in a **Business Logic Layer** with `methodOne()` and `methodTwo()` being in a **Data Access Layer**.

The Data Access Layer should be injected ([IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) into the Business Logic Layer so it can be mocked out. That way when you are testing the Condition method you would pass in a mock Data Access Layer that doesn't actually connect to a database.

That way you can check that Condition was called, as you are now, without any side-effects like writing to the database. When you encounter situations like this it helps you to break out your code into a better architecture and could ultimately lead you to investigate [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Comment: I see what you mean and I am agree , with your solution. beside this I just want to know if there is anyway to only assert an internal method called without executing it, with partial mock ?